# Compare the times of different files using shell script

Tags: shell-script, files, timestamps

I have a file with below contents. Here i need to compare the timestamp of `HIW.ear` in the first line with the timestamp of `.jars` from the second line and i am running out of ideas on how to do this. Any help on this please. The .ear timestamp should be lesser than all the other .jar timestamps.

```
[rba@ci01 UAT]$ cat UAT1.txt
UAT - NODE1,May18;21:00;HIW.ear
May18;21:01;O.jar
May18;21:01;Com.jar
May18;21:01;D.jar
May18;21:01;F.jar
```

Comment: That isnt a typo, Pulled in that value from another variable into this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `awk` both timestamps to extract them, then arrange the timestamp in the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss` format, convert them to epoch time with `date --date='2021/05/18 21:00:22' +"%s"` and then compare the epoch time to see which is greater.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what should happen if the comparison fails, but given

```
$ cat -n UAT1.txt
     1  UAT - NODE1,May18;21:00;HIW.ear
     2  May18;21:01;O.jar
     3  May18;21:01;Com.jar
     4  May18;20:59;D.jar
     5  May18;21:01;F.jar
```

then using perl, with the [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Piece#Date-Calculations) module:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -F';' -pe '
    if($. == 1) {
      ($s,$md) = split(/,/,$F[0]);
      $t0 = Time::Piece->strptime($md . $F[1], "%B%d%H:%M");
      next
    }
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime($F[0] . $F[1], "%B%d%H:%M");
    die "Timestamp out of order" if $t < $t0;
  ' UAT1.txt
UAT - NODE1,May18;21:00;HIW.ear
May18;21:01;O.jar
May18;21:01;Com.jar
Timestamp out of order at -e line 8, <> line 4.
```

Note that it's not clear from your example whether the month specifier should be `%B` or `%b` since you happen to have chosen the one month whose English full name and abbreviated name are the same.

You could do something similar with GNU awk (`gawk`) but you'd need to roll your own `strptime` using string functions to wrangle the elements into a format suitable for `mktime`.